# Change header of an inline datepicker angular material

Tags: javascript, angular, datepicker, angular-material2

To change the header of a datepicker in angular material we use `[calendarHeaderComponent]` e.g

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Date</mat-label>
  <input formControlName="date" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" />
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker">
    <mat-icon matDatepickerToggleIcon svgIcon="calendar_day"></mat-icon>
  </mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker color="primary" [calendarHeaderComponent]="datePickerHeader" #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

To get the datepicker inline we use `mat-calendar` directly

```html
  <mat-calendar [(selected)]="date"></mat-calendar>
```

The challenge is that If I try to use `calendarHeaderComponent` directive on this component it throws error that this attribute is not allowed here. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming **customDatePickerHeader** is your custom header component.
Try binding as follows:

```
<mat-calendar [headerComponent]="customDatePickerHeader" [(selected)]="date"></mat-calendar>
```

I'd have referenced a documentation but not sure it's easy to find one for the inline mat-calendar component. Will edit post if I manage to find it.